# IE7/8 fix for background-size: cover

Tags: css, drupal-7

I know there are posts on how to fix `background-size: cover` for IE7/8, but my background is a slideshow built in Drupal. I loaded the jquery.backgroundSize.js by louisremi but nothing happened. I added the JS to the site so it is loading, but do I need to configure something to get it to work? I'm no good with JS.

Right now I used the filter method: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

But it is only bringing in one static image. Is there anyway to retain my slideshow in IE?

The site Droga5 did it, but I can't tell how.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IE filter for this. In your css add:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='image.gif',
sizingMethod='scale');

-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='image.gif',
sizingMethod='scale')";
```

If you are changing the html *img src* using javascript, you also have to change it in the filter.

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with jQuery or Zepto method, here is the solution: https://github.com/pakcheong/jqthumb